# How to get embedded Google form to scroll with entire webpage, not within it's own frame

Tags: iframe, google-forms, fullpage.js

Ok I'm losing my mind here. I don't have any experience with coding, but there's got to be a way to fix this. I have a simple Google Form to add to my Google Site that clients can fill out to get in contact with me. I have the Form embedded into the site, but it looks terrible with all the scrolls that are added in. I've played around and changed the height=100% and width=100% and scrolling=no. In changing this, I can get the Form to look perfect on the desktop view of my site, but as soon as I change to tablet or phone view, the Form cuts off. All I'm trying to do is have the form format to whatever method it's being viewed on (i.e. desktop, tablet, or phone) and have the form scroll TOGETHER with the web page, NOT with a separate scroll within the frame. Below is the original raw code before I changed anything. HELP!

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSei4RDbNOhfL6gI8BMZAG4wyagdbs195bYqtrf2P-4UXgRoDw/viewform?embedded=true" width="640" height="979" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Loading…</iframe>
```

Comment: Difficult to know what's the issue if we can't see a reproduction of it or a video at least